# REST API translations

Tags: rest, api, internationalization

In my api I have a API builder where a user selects form a from down GET, PUT or POST. I am getting my app translated and wondering if GET, PUT and POST should be translated or remain in English as it is part of API spec?

What should be done?

Thank you

Comment: Keep them English. Otherwise you risk confusing people when you are displaying something they might not expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my api I have a API builder where a user selects form a from down GET, PUT or POST. I am getting my app translated and wondering if GET, PUT and POST should be translated or remain in English as it is part of API spec?

You should use the [registered](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) spellings for the request method tokens.